# EReadError with message 'Property Persistence does Not exist' при попытке скомпилировать проект

Tags: delphi

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, решил продолжыть работу над одной из своих прог, 
открыл исходник, ничего не правил, пытаюсь скомпилировать, и тут выдает ошибку

> Delphi: EReadError with message
> 'Property Persistence does Not exist'

выполнение останавливается на строке

> Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);

почему вылетает ошибка никак не могу понять, раньше все работало как часы.... может кто то сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798382/delphi-ereaderror-with-message-property-persistence-does-not-exist)

> 1. Open the Form in Delphi IDE
> 2. Use Alt + F12 to edit the .DFM source
> 3. Search the "Persistence" property
> 4. Delete the line with "Persistence" property

если перевести:

1. открыть dfm ресурс
2. найти свойство "Persistence"
3. удалить эту строку

Comment: нету там такого свойства Persistence (((

Answer (score 1):

Версии Делфи совпадают?

Такие ошибки бывают, когда проект более старшей версии пробуют открыть версией младшей.

Comment: да, всегда работаю только на Delphi 7, проект создавался на этом же компе, на етом же ПО!